# Highlight entire row on mouseover table

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, onclick

I have HTML table like this (self generated by tool):

1. I am having trouble to highlight the entire row using Jquery
2. I am trying to achieve if I click one cell it needs to be highlighted and I move to other cell it needs to be not highlighted .

Below is my table but it actually starts with td because its part/inside of other  table elements:

```
<td class="PTChildPivotTable">
<table tabindex="0" id="saw_437_c" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="TTHC OOLT" id="id1" style="font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;font-style:italic;font-weight:normal;">XYZ</td>
<td class="TTHC PTLC OOLT" id="id2" style="font-family:Arial-Italic;font-size:16px;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;">PQR</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="TTHC OOLT" id="id3" style="font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;font-style:italic;font-weight:normal;">XYZ2</td>
<td class="TTHC PTLC OOLT" id="id4" style="font-family:Arial-Italic;font-size:16px;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;">PQR2</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</td>
```

I am trying below Jquery code and it does highlight one col of one row but not the entire row while hover:

```
  <style style="text/css">
        /* Define the hover highlight color for the table row */
        .PTChildPivotTable td:hover {
              background-color: #ffff99;
        }

      .PTChildPivotTable tr:hover {
              background-color: #ff0000;
        }

    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

 $("td").on("click", function() {
         $( this ).css({
          "background-color": "#0093e0",
          "border": "10px"
        });
        });

    </script>
```

1. The idea is once I mousehover one row the entire `<tr>` should be highlighted which is 2 TD values as XYZ , PQR . When I hover to next row XYZ2, PQR2 needs to be highlighted. In my code only one value can highlight at a time.
2. 2nd requirement is, if I click XYZ its background color needs to be blue (#0093e0). When I click PQR, the previous XYZ needs to be white but PQR needs to be blue and same behavior across other cells.

Comment: The requirement is not clear, please elaborate properly.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

**CSS**

```
.PTChildPivotTable tr:hover {
  background-color: #ff0000 !important;
}

.PTChildPivotTable td.clicked {
  background-color: #0093e0 !important;
  border: 10px !important;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(".PTChildPivotTable td").on("click", function() {
    $(".PTChildPivotTable td").removeClass('clicked')
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
});
```

Here you have a fiddle https://fiddle.jshell.net/rigobauer/8bp2xokc/

You don't mention it, but I guess you're going to need to be able to unselect the highlighted `td` clicking again on it. Otherwise, you're always going to have one cell selected. If that's the case just change the jQuery a little bit...

```
$(".PTChildPivotTable td").on("click", function() {
    $(".PTChildPivotTable td").not(this).removeClass('clicked');
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
});
```

I hope it helps

Comment: a-iglesias - Your answer perfectly works fine in jfiddle . Challenge for me is to get this fit into pre-existing tool generated code and make custom changes on top of it ... I didn't design the table rather pulled it from tool . Somehow tool is not allowing me diff color on tr:hover but only on td:hover .. that caused only 1 cell highlight at one time and not complete row :-( Also the toggleclass works great in jfiddle but I can't make it work .

Comment: a-iglesias - do you know anyway to replace the style : background-color: below in onclick event ? I dont want rgb(156,172,201) but replace with my own color "#0093e0"   <td class="TTHC OOLT" id="e_saw_1199_c_1_0_21" style="font-family: Lato; font-size: 16px; font-style: italic; font-weight: normal; background-image: none; background-color: rgb(156, 172, 201);">XYZ</td>

Comment: About the hover row problem, maybe you have more css styles that are having priority over the ones you're defining here. Try using `!important` (I've edited the question)

Comment: About the `toggleClass()` function, first check if the class is being applied to the `td` using your browser inspector tool. If the class is being applied, then is probable the same css priority problem. Try `!important` again. If the class is not being applied, tell me if there's any console error.

Comment: About the replace color question, when you click on that cell the `.clicked` class should overwrite that color. Try to make work the two previous points and this should be solved too.

Comment: a-iglesias - I fix the problem with !important . thats killer clue . thank you so much . But the hovering is still an issue .its not changing the color for entire row but only that hovered td . But anyways hover is not my priority and thank you very much for the help . Btw you are from beautiful city .googled it !

Comment: Great to hear!! And thanks for the kind words of my city! Have a nice day and happy coding!